# Изменить форму input-а

Tags: html, css

Вывожу в таблице в инпуты значения из бд.

```
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="doc_publish" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($users['doc_publish'], ENT_QUOTES)?>" id="example-text-input"></td>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как  сделать так, чтобы данные показывались целиком? Может перенос строки сделать как-то...

Answer (score 2):

В нативном инпуте перенос строки сделать невозможно, используйте для многострочных данных textarea:

```css
textarea{
  display:block;
  height: 100px;
  width:90%;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="example-text-input"  name="doc_publish">
  <?=htmlspecialchars($users['doc_publish'], ENT_QUOTES)?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('textarea').on('paste input', function () {
    if ($(this).outerHeight() > this.scrollHeight){
        $(this).height(1)
    }
    while ($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))){
        $(this).height($(this).height() + 1)
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <textarea id="txtInput"></textarea>
</body>
```